# Notion wm independent workspaces

Tags: window-manager, multi-monitor, notion

Does anyone know how to configure the Notion WM (fork of ion3) to have workspace switching spearate for each monitor while still be able to move windows between monitors.

That is I want to be able to change the workspace displayed on monitor 1 without affecting monitor 2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to configure anything to get this behavior. What you describe is the default behavior. (At least for me on Ubuntu)

- Switching between Monitors: super + I
- Creating a workspace on the active Monitor: super + F9
- Switching between Workspaces on the active Monitor super + <1, 2, 3, ...>
  (=> won't effect the active workspace on other Monitors)
- Moving windows by super + t to tag it, then switch to the desired tile, workspace, monitor and attach it by super + k, a.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu's default window manager.